# MySQL selecting multiple fields with IS NOT NULL isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

I have a query that transfers data from multiple slave tables into a single master table. Here's an example of one of my queries:

```
$insert = mysql_query("
INSERT IGNORE INTO master (title, description, keywords, url, uniqueid, city, state, zip, datetime, expiretime)
SELECT title, description, keywords, url, uniqueid, city, state, zip, datetime, expiretime
FROM slave1 WHERE zip IS NOT NULL AND keywords IS NOT NULL AND city IS NOT NULL") or die(mysql_error());
```

After running this query, rows of data are being inserted into `master` with either *some or all of the fields* `NULL` where I specified them to be `NOT NULL` (the fields being `zip`, `keywords`, and `city`)

It seems like mysql is completely ignoring the `IS NOT NULL` parameter. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Could you show an example from your data?

Comment: Are you sure that the data inserted is actually `NULL`, and not just an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace `zip IS NOT NULL` to `TRIM(zip) <> ""`

Comment: This answer plus Michael's makes sense and solved the problem. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect *uniqueid* is the primary key. Probably, your *master* table already contains rows with the same keys, which have empty values of *city*, etc. In that case you should use REPLACE instead of INSERT IGNORE.